# no html tag in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am new to rails and just created a new project. I created the following view in Haml, index.html.haml to be exact. However this is the source I get when I run the app. I get no html, or title tags that I also created in Haml. The first is the source, the second is the contents of my Haml file.

```
<h2>'All Posts'</h2>
<table id='posts'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Post Title</th>
      <th>Post Entry</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody></tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>First Post</td>
    <td>Oylesine bir seyler</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The index.html.haml file:

```
%h2 'All Posts'

%table#posts
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Post Title
      %th Post Entry

  %tbody
  - @posts.each do |post|
    %tr
      %td= post.title
      %td= post.body
```

This is the application.html.haml file that I created:

```
!!! 5
%html
  %head
    %title Rotten Potatoes!
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application'
    = javascript_include_tag 'application'
    = csrf_meta_tags

  %body
    = yield
```

Am I missing something here?

Here is the controller code:

```
class MoviesController < ActionController::Base
  def index
    @movies = Movie.all
  end

  def show
    id = params[:id]
    @movie = Movie.find_by_id(id)
  end
end
```

Comment: Post the relevant controller code too please.

Comment: Your layout isn't being picked up. Where is your `application.html.haml` file? It should be at `app/views/layouts/application.html.haml`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your movies controller to inherit from `ApplicationController` instead of `ActionController::Base`:

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Delete %html

See [this](https://github.com/sporkd/compass-html5-boilerplate) and [this](https://gist.github.com/716066)

application.html.haml example:

```
!!! 5
-# http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither
-ie_html :class => 'no-js oldie', :lang => 'en' do
  %head
    -# To render a different stylesheet partial inside the head (i.e. for admin layout)
    -# just copy _stylesheets.html.haml, and point to that partial instead.
    = render "layouts/head", :stylesheet_partial => "layouts/stylesheets"

  %body{ :class => "#{controller.controller_name}" }
    #container
      %header#header
        = render "layouts/header"

      #main{ :role => 'main' }
        = render "layouts/flashes"
        = yield

      %footer#footer
        = render "layouts/footer"

    -# Javascript at the bottom for fast page loading
    = render "layouts/javascripts"
```

Comment: didn't work.. i deleted the %html bu still no html tag on the source. is this also why my stylesheet doesn't apply to the website?

Comment: I did look at the files on github, but I couldn't see anything specific that would remove my html tags. Is there something specific I need to look for in the code you pasted

Comment: It seems that the app does not use the layout.

Comment: I have a working version on my computer, and checking the log I found the difference. The working one has the following,`Rendered movies/index.html.haml within layouts/application (146.0ms)
Compiled application.css  (20ms)  (pid 4502)
Compiled application.js  (52ms)  (pid 4502)
Compiled jquery.js  (36ms)  (pid 4502)
Compiled jquery_ujs.js  (34ms)  (pid 4502)
Completed 200 OK in 694ms (Views: 692.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)`, whereas the non-working one has, `Rendered movies/index.html.haml (12.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 92ms (Views: 88.6ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)`

Answer (score 0):

1.) The simplest solution is to rename your application.html.haml to movies.html.haml in app/views/layouts directory, because Rails first looks for a file in app/views/layouts with the same base name as the controller.

If there is no controller specific layout, Rails should use theoretically app/views/layouts/application.html.erb or app/views/layouts/application.html.haml. This doesn't work for me either in Rails 3.2.2.

2.) Other possibility is to define 'application' as layout for your controller:

```
class MoviesController < ActionController::Base
layout "application"

  def index
    @movies = Movie.all
  end

  def show
    id = params[:id]
    @movie = Movie.find_by_id(id)
  end
end
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

remove views/layouts/application.html.erb
the erb is eclipsing the applcation.html.haml